# Можно ли сделать дебаг MediaPlayer информативнее в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, отладка, mediaplayer

MediaPlayer в моем приложении не принимает какой-то поток, но я не могу через дебаг его выявить, чтобы предпринять какие-то меры, потому что в дебаге очень-очень мало информации, если сравнивать с IJK, VLC или Exo плеерами.

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы MediaPlayer выводил больше информации в дебаг?